# Make javascript click function from input button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, button

simple question but i just wanna know if I have the javascript correct to be called when this input button is clicked. I cant use an id on this button tho. So how would i call a click event in javascript instead of using hte onclick im using currently.

```
 <input type="button" class="text" value="@video.Text" onclick="@String.Format("videochange('{0}')",url);" />
```

Comment: you could select it by class, by tagname, by attribute value, or by it's position in the DOM

Comment: i know that but im actually asking for someone to show me the correct format because i tried it before and couldnt get it to work correctly.

Comment: What does the html look like once its loaded? Does value="@video.Text" remain like that???

Comment: no that changes per the model its being loaded from.

Comment: yeah that would be fine

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this,

```
<input type="button" class="text" value="@video.Text" />

$(".test[type='button']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    videochange('url');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways,

**1- Pure javaScript:**

```
<input type="button" class="text" value="@video.Text" />
<script>
buttons = document.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
for( var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++ )
{
  Btn = buttons[i];
  if( Btn.className == 'text' )
  {
   Btn.onclick = function()
   {
    /* [...] */
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

**2- [ OR In jQuery ]**

```
$('.text').click(function()
{
  /* [...] */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, then a better approach would be to not have inline scripts at all (really considered bad form).

Try something like this, instead:

```
<input type="button" 
      class="text" 
      value="@video.Text" 
   data-url="@String.Format('{0}',url);" />
```

(broke it into separate lines for ease of readability ... also, depending on how the template renders, you may run into accidental issues of terminating strings improperly, which is why I changed the "{0}" to '{0}')

Now, in your javascript:

```
// when the dom is ready
$(function() {
    $('.text').click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        videochange(url);
    });
});
```

This properly separates your roles and responsibilities... server-side code stays server-side, and provides the data to the view. The view/client-side scripting then handles view-side interaction, without messily trying to merge syntax between two different languages.